# how to get callback on selecting/clicking an option in ionic-select-option

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ion-select

ionic verison : 6.12.3
ionic-angular:

```
<ion-select (ionChange)="onChange($event,item,'a')"> 
     <ion-select-option value="f" >Female</ion-select-option>
     <ion-select-option value="m" >male</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

I tried giving `(click)="someFunction()"` in `ion-select-option`, but not working.
any workaround to achieve? onclicking male or female i need a callback(not on submiting or clicking ok).

Comment: I think it should be `ion-option` instead of `ion-select-option` please check it and let me know. If it is `ion-option` then check my answer. Best wishes. :-)

Comment: ion-option throws not a know element error in my version 6.12.3 @SJNF

Comment: ok wait let me check

Comment: 6.12.3 is your angular version? @MOHAMEDSIKKANDARAFZALM

Comment: No , 6.12.3 is my ionic version, and Angular CLI: 9.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code. You can try this =>
**HTML:**

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="myProp" (ngModelChange)="ngMode($event)" (ionChange)="ionChangeEvent($event)" placeholder="Please Select State">
    <ion-option  value="0" >Female</ion-option>
    <ion-option  value="1">Male</ion-option>
    <ion-option  value="2">Other</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

**TS:**

```
 myProp:any;
  ionChangeEvent($event){
    console.log("From Ioc Change:"+$event);
    //console.log(this.myProp);
  }
  ngMode($event){
    console.log("From ngModel Change:"+$event);
    //console.log(this.myProp);
  }
```

**Note:** Both `ionChange` and `ngModelChange` is working fine. Check [Stackblitz Demo Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-3-how-to-set-ion-option-as-selected-jgsonf?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html).

Comment: ion-option throws not a known element error in my version 6.12.3

Comment: for ionic 6 (and possibly some time before) the correct option elements for an ion-select are no longer ion-option, but ion-select-option